# Wordcloud only illustrates letters no words

Tags: python, text, nlp, preprocessor, word-cloud

I am currently analyzing text data and have among other things extracted the nouns from the corpus.

And yes, I am a novice and I am here to learn and improve through my mistakes.

When I create a wordcloud based on the column of extracted nouns, the word cloud only shows letters and symbols, but not a single word.

**My main concern is not the wordcloud**, but since I am analyzing the text further, topic modelling and aim to develop a predictive model, I want to ensure that the column has no issues for further analysis.

```
from textblob import TextBlob
def get_nouns(text):
   blob = TextBlob(text)
   return [ word for (word,tag) in blob.tags if tag == "NN"]

df_unique['nouns'] = df_unique['tokenized'].apply(get_nouns)

#nouns wordcloud
all_words_xn = []
for line in df_unique['nouns']: 
    all_words_xn.extend(line)

# create a word frequency dictionary
wordfreq = Counter(all_words_xn)
# draw a Word Cloud with word frequencies
wordcloud = WordCloud(width=900,
                  height=500,
                  max_words=50,
                  max_font_size=100,
                  relative_scaling=0.5,
                  colormap='Blues',
                  normalize_plurals=True).generate_from_frequencies(wordfreq)
plt.figure(figsize=(17,14))
plt.imshow(wordcloud, interpolation='bilinear')
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

[Current Wordcloud output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCiOs.png)

**Column with nouns from the dataframe**

```
0                                                 ['lot']
1                           ['weapon', 'gun', 'instance']
2                               ['drive', 'drive', 'car']
3                                ['felt', 'guy', 'stage']
4       ['price', 'launch', 'ryse', 'son', 'ip', 'cryt...
5       ['drivatar', 'crash', 'guy', 'track', 'use', '...
6                                      ['spark', 'thing']
7       ['stream', 'player', 'linux', 'start', 'stream...
8                    ['kill', 'game', 'absolute', 'shit']
9                   ['breed', 'stealth', 'horse', 'duck']
10                                      ['beach', 'duty']
11                                                     []
12                                    ['europe', 'guess']
13                              ['power', 'cloud', 'god']
14                        ['gameplay', 'footage', 'zoom']
15                                                     []
16      ['stream', 'play', 'game', 'week', 'gdex', 'co...
17                                               ['edit']
19                     ['halo', 'clip', 'lot', 'journey']
21      ['thing', 'master', 'chief', 'shawl', 'help', ...
22      ['respect', 'respawn', 'trailer', 'gameplay', ...

Name: nouns, Length: 7523, dtype: object
```

Comment: Usually this means that you’re iterating through a string when you intend to be iterating through something else, like a list of tokens or a list of sentences. In your case, it looks like maybe you’re passing in tokenized data to textblob and then textblob is reading those tokens character by character. As a general debugging technique, it’s best to cut away (temporarily) things that don’t matter and try to find your problem, so you could do through print statements, returning early, commenting out code, using a visual debugger, etc. I would recommend looking at what blob.tags returns.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I am unfortunately not yet that well-versed. However, based on your suggestion I think the problem lies here

`all_words_xn = []
for line in df_unique['nouns']: 
    all_words_xn.extend(line)`


As you say I think I am passing through a my tokenized data as character by character. But I don't know if it is the `line in df_unique['nouns']:` resulting in this problem. Do you know how it could be improved so that the tokens are passed?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is just fine. There must be an error in the preprocessing pipeline you're not showing here.

See below for a complete working example based on your code:

```
from textblob import TextBlob
from collections import Counter
from wordcloud import WordCloud

texts = ["This is some text about thing", "This is another text about gun", "This is a text about car"]
df_unique = pd.DataFrame({"tokenized":texts})

def get_nouns(text):
    blob = TextBlob(text)
    return [ word for (word,tag) in blob.tags if tag == "NN"]

df_unique['nouns'] = df_unique['tokenized'].apply(get_nouns)

#nouns wordcloud
all_words_xn = []
for line in df_unique['nouns']: 
    all_words_xn.extend(line)


# create a word frequency dictionary
wordfreq = Counter(all_words_xn)
# draw a Word Cloud with word frequencies
wordcloud = WordCloud(width=900,
                  height=500,
                  max_words=50,
                  max_font_size=100,
                  relative_scaling=0.5,
                  colormap='Blues',
                  normalize_plurals=True).generate_from_frequencies(wordfreq)
plt.figure(figsize=(17,14))
plt.imshow(wordcloud, cmap="gray_r")
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

[image]